# Tensorflow 2.0 train model on single GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I want to train a sequential tensorflow (version 2.3.0) model on a single NVIDIA graphic card (RTX 2080 super). I am using the following code snippet to build and train the model. However, everytime I am running this code I do not see any GPU utilization. Any suggestion how to modify my code so I can run it on 1 GPU?

```
strategy = tf.distribute.OneDeviceStrategy(device="/GPU:0")
with strategy.scope():
    num_classes=len(pd.unique(cats.No))
    model = BuildModel((image_height, image_width, 3), num_classes)
    model.summary()
    model=train_model(model,valid_generator,train_generator,EPOCHS,BATCH_SIZE)
```

Comment: If you only have 1 GPU why are you using tf.distribute?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to make sure the training is done on GPU rather than  CPU.  It doesnot work because I can see there  is no computation  is done on my GPU

Comment: have you any news about this problem?I have the same

Answer (score 2):

run the code below to see if tensorflow detects your GPU.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
print(tf.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
!python --version
```

Comment: it does  detect the gpu:   Num GPUs Available:  1
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-1-b5bb3d29fd0a>:6: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
Python 3.7.7